# How to set a Generic object within a standard class in Java?

Tags: java, object, generics

**Background Context:**

I have a non-generic class that represents a complex 3D model. I also have a series of standard 3D geometric classes (Sphere, Cube, Cuboid) that all inherit from an abstract class so all the child classes inherit the same fields and functions. So each class needs to be able to work with the Complex 3D model class, which doesn't inherit from the abstract class (it doesn't have the need for the same fields/functions).

So I want to use all of the child classes with the complex model class. Specifically, one child class can work with complex model when needed by the user, so this will be saved as a field to this class for as long as the user needs it. The complex class will need to access fields and functions from these objects, so I thought using a generic function could apply to all the simple 3D mesh classes that have the same fields/functions.

**Question**

Let's say I have a non-generic class where I want a field of that class to be a generic type. I want the non-generic class to be able to handle a variety of user-created types.

I want a generic method inside the non-generic class that can set the generic field, like this:

```
void <T> setGenericObject(T object){
    genericField = object;
}
```

However, I don't know how to declare the generic field properly. I don't want to create a generic class just for one small field of it (since working with other objects is only a small part of the functionality of that class). How would I properly declare this genericField variable inside my class for this to work?

Comment: While you can’t make only a field generic, you can use the erasure for `T`, which would be `Object`. What are you trying to do with the field?

Comment: The field will update it's rotation along with the main class. It will become temporarily part of a 3D model until the generic type is either reset or changed to null.

Comment: There's not enough context to offer anything more helpful than "just use Object".

Comment: Hmm, that might work in accordance with maybe another function that extracts the methods from the generic object.

Comment: You're stuck with a type parameter on the class if you want a generic field. That's just how generics work in Java. If you edit the question to include more context about what you're doing (or ask a new one), it may be the case that we can offer alternatives to using generics. (Also see http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Radiodef I added some more context for the question. Hope that helps others understand my question better.

Comment: If you don't add the type parameter to the class, It's unavailable in the field declaration. This means that `Object` is the only type for `genericField` that will work for this method (if the type parameter is upper bounded by a single type, you may be able to that type).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could declare the field to be of type `Object` and set it equal to the parameter. All classes in Java extend `Object` class, so you can use it as generic type:

```
private Object genericObject;

public void setGenericObject(Object object) {
    this.genericObject = object;
}
```

Then if you want then to invoke a method that doesn’t belong to `Object`, you can do so with a cast:

```
public void executeMethod() {
    ((ClassName) this.genericObject).methodName();
}
```

Be aware of `ClassCastException`s, though.

Comment: Sorry for grammar and sintax, i'm Italain

Comment: I pretty much ended up using this, with the exception of using Reflection to look up fields and methods.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create an inner class:

```
public class Sample{
    //other functionality

    private class Inner<T>{
        T g;

        public T getG() {
            return g;
        }

        public void setG(T g) {
            this.g = g;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it could be used like this:

```
Sample sample = new Sample();
Sample.Inner<Float> inner = sample.new Inner<>();
inner.setG(new Float(0.1));
Float g = inner.getG();
```